# Showing dataset with dates and times in recharts linechart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am using a linechart from recharts to show a value over time.

The linechart code looks like this.

```
export default function LineGraphs({ Data }) {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>A demo of synchronized AreaCharts</h4>
      <LineChart
        width={500}
        height={100}
        data={data}
        syncId="anyId"
        margin={{
          top: 10,
          right: 30,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Magic" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
      </LineChart>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to show a this dataset in the linechart, which has dates, and then the timestamp of the magic value,i.e.,

```
{2020-10-05: Array(5), 2020-10-07: Array(4), 2020-10-09: Array(3), 2020-05-21: Array(3), 2020-05-22: Array(98), …}
2020-05-21: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
2020-05-22: (98) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2020-05-24: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2020-06-04: (65) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2020-06-05: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Where inside of the arrays under the dates is,

```
0: {created: 1601820360, magic: -0.1, magnitude: 0.1, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
1: {created: 1601820365, magic: -0.8, magnitude: 0.8, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
2: {created: 1601900938, magic: -0.2, magnitude: 0.2, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
3: {created: 1601900956, magic: -0.2, magnitude: 0.2, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
4: {created: 1601900971, magic: 0.2, magnitude: 0.2, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
```

Currently I'm using this to check what data is there,

```
Object.keys(Data).map(function(key, item) {
        console.log(Data[key]);
        
      })
```

I'm trying to understand how best to take this data into this graph - The total dataset to begin with then I will filter the dates in the application. When I try and do the above code I'm struggling to put it in the right format to have it display properly

Comment: Could you tell what you want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that in recharts, your dataset should always be an array of datapoint objects. You should not typically have nested objects. If you do want to, then you are going to need to pass a getter function into the dataKey property on your line instead of the string.
The docs do indicate this as an option: https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Line

As far as the dataKey for the X and Y axes go, you are going to need to pass a string or a number. So I recommend formatting the data you pass into the chart as an array of objects, with each object representing a single data point.